# SQLite Cursor is incorrectly initialized

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I am getting this error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 28 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.**

Here is my cursor from my DB handler class...are there any visible errors?

```
    // retrieve a single friend
public Friend getFriend(int id){
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

Friend friend = null;

if( checkIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot( TABLE_FRIENDS, KEY_ID, id ) )
{
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_FRIENDS, new String[] { 
            KEY_ID, KEY_GEN, KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_MIDDLENAME, 
            KEY_LASTNAME, KEY_BD, KEY_BM, KEY_BY, KEY_RN, KEY_HC,
            KEY_HT, KEY_NB, KEY_NS, KEY_SP, KEY_RS, KEY_CH, KEY_P,
            KEY_FC, KEY_FMU, KEY_LFM, KEY_FMO, KEY_LFMG, KEY_FTS,
            KEY_FAF, KEY_LFFS, KEY_HO, KEY_OC, KEY_PP}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }



    friend = new Friend(cursor.getInt(0),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getInt(5),
            cursor.getInt(6),
            cursor.getInt(7),
            cursor.getInt(8),
            cursor.getString(9),
            cursor.getString(10),
            cursor.getString(11),
            cursor.getInt(12),
            cursor.getInt(13),
            cursor.getString(14),
            cursor.getString(15),
            cursor.getInt(16),
            cursor.getInt(17),
            cursor.getString(18),
            cursor.getString(19),
            cursor.getString(20),
            cursor.getString(21),
            cursor.getString(22),
            cursor.getString(23),
            cursor.getString(24),
            cursor.getString(25),
            cursor.getString(26),
            cursor.getString(27),
            cursor.getString(28));
}

return friend;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column indexes are 0-based and not 1-based. Your cursor has 28 columns and you're trying to read the 29th one.

Consider using `getColumnIndex()` instead (or better yet, `getColumnIndexOrThrow()`) to get column index by column name instead of hardcoding your indexes.

Comment: Thank you laalto!  I will try this.

Comment: Consider using `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` instead …

Comment: Thank you laalto and -CL.  That seems to have worked!  I apologize for the slow response.